# PHP replace string with values from mutiple array

Tags: php, arrays

PHP replace string with values from multiple array.

For example, I have string like this: `Hello [%A%] [%B%]`

And I have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Sam
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Taylor
            [1] => luke    
        )
)
```

I want to generate output as an array like that:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Hello John Taylor
   [1] => Hello Sam luke
)
```

Comment: No questionmark, no error, no code, so have a try and come back. Tip: `str_replace` and `foreach` .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$template = "Hello [%A%] [%B%]";

$array = array(
    "A" => array("John", "Sam"),
    "B" => array("Taylor", "luke"),
);

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $key => $values)
{
    foreach($values as $key2 => $value)
    {
        if(empty($new_array[$key2]))
        {
            $new_array[$key2] = $template;
        }

        $new_array[$key2] = str_replace("[%".$key."%]", $value, $new_array[$key2]);
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello John Taylor
    [1] => Hello Sam luke
)
```